# Bug while looping through list

Tags: python

So I read this question at [math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7204/limit-of-nested-radical-sqrt1-2-sqrt13-sqrt1-cdots?rq=1) and decided to run a loop to check the answer for myself. I know the proof there is rigorous, so I never really doubted it, but it's good when you can see things work out. Apparently stackoverflow doesn't support LaTex, (which seems quite reasonable considering this is a programming site, not a math one) so I am posting a screenshot to the question in case the link goes down or something.

[image: Ramanujan's famous nested radical]

Now I wrote this code to simulate the above expression, obviously calculating it till infinity is absurd, so I decided to do it till n=999, seemed reasonable to me as I didn't have an idea of how fast the expression converges. For those without a math background, Ignore the `lim` I am trying to calculate the given expression for n=999.

```
>>>l=list(range(1,1000))
>>>from math import sqrt as s
>>>p=1
>>>while l:
       a=l.pop()
       a*=p
       a+=1
       a=s(a)
       p=a
>>>p
2.0
```

I expect the answer to be 3 not 2. Also note that I am *not* asking for a method to compute this function, I am asking for the bug in my code. You *could* provide me with a function of your own, but the primary intention of this question is to locate the bug in the code I wrote, which sadly I cannot find.

Comment: Whether your code has a bug or not (it seems too), 1000 iterations probably won't be enough. Any modern computer will easily handle 1 million, and 100 million wouldn't be a stretch. Also, why make the range a list when you can just do a for over the range. It would be more efficient.

Comment: @Linuxios I don't think the problem is with too small n. It should converge faster than that. It _is_ converging to 2 here, supported in part by the fact that it comes out to a nice 2.0 instead of some decimal.

Comment: @Linuxios I will try checking for larger n though.

Comment: Don't bother. It converges to 2.0 for me on n of 1 million.

Comment: Your code is inverted. Each value of `a` needs to be multiplied by the square root of a function of larger values of `a`, but you multiply by `p`, which is a function of smaller values of `a`.

Comment: Converges to 3 for n = 43, if you change the range to go from 2 to n.

Comment: @chepner p is a function of larger values, I am computing backwards? a=l.pop()?

Comment: @M4rtini yep.I did 1 extra iteration.

Comment: I removed my answer, didn't realize that pop() removes from the end. I blame unidiomatic Python, it can't be my mistake, can it? :-)

Comment: POP _always_ removes from the end of a stack, so should expect as much. One word my friend, **tradition**

Comment: It removes from the _top_ of a stack, traditionally. Stacks traditionally don't have a beginning or an end, so that doesn't help me. Anyway I'd use a for loop over reversed(range(2, 1000)) for readability.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich To each his own I guess, but it always seemed intuitive to me that the top of the stack would be the end element. Also, wouldn't `range(999,1,-1)` be just as readable _and_ shorter to write?

Comment: or maybe even `range(2,1000)[::-1]` BTW, that doesn't create a list, check at the interpreter, it returns `range(999,1,-1)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you want to be using `range(2, 1000)`.  If you go all the way down to `1` you end up with an extra `sqrt(1 + ...)` where `...` is the formula you are attempting to solve.